# Multiline editable text field in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-catalina

I'm looking to create an editable multi-line text box in Swift UI for macOS. I'd like to create a syntax highlighting text editor, so it'd be multi-line and change styles throughout the lines. Is this possible with the framework in its current state? I can find barely any documentation about it online.

Comment: It looks like SwiftUI now has a TextEditor component here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor But it doesn't support changing styles like colours throughout the line

Answer (score 1):

it can be useful, this is my first solution to get an NSTextView with SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI
import os

let uiLog = OSLog(subsystem: "com.visual-science.CryptiK", category: "UI")

class  EditorCoordinator : NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {
  let textView: NSTextView;
  let scrollView : NSScrollView
  let text : Binding<NSAttributedString>

  init(binding: Binding<NSAttributedString>) {
    text = binding

    textView = NSTextView(frame: .zero)
    textView.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
    textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(text.wrappedValue)
    textView.textColor = NSColor.textColor

    scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: .zero)
    scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
    scrollView.autohidesScrollers = false
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
    scrollView.documentView = textView

    super.init()
    textView.delegate = self
  }

  func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    switch  notification.name {
    case NSText.didChangeNotification :
      text.wrappedValue = (notification.object as? NSTextView)?.textStorage ?? NSAttributedString(string: "")
    default:
      os_log(.error, log: uiLog, "Coordinator received unwanted notification")
    }
  }

}

struct DataTextEditorView: View, NSViewRepresentable {
  typealias Coordinator = EditorCoordinator
  typealias NSViewType = NSScrollView

  let text : Binding<NSAttributedString>

  func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<DataTextEditorView>) -> DataTextEditorView.NSViewType {
    os_log(.info, log: uiLog, "%@", context.coordinator.scrollView)
    return context.coordinator.scrollView
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSScrollView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<DataTextEditorView>) {
    os_log(.debug, log: uiLog, "%@", context.coordinator.self)
    os_log(.debug, log: uiLog, "%@", text.wrappedValue)
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> EditorCoordinator {
    os_log(.info, log: uiLog, "makeCoordinator")
    let coordinator =  EditorCoordinator(binding: text)
    return coordinator
  }

}
```

If like me, you just need to edit some text without attributes, you can replace NSAttributedString with just String and adapt the code for this simpler case.

Comment: Something important here, the SwiftUI struct is created a lot of time, but the coordinator is cached somewhat... then everything is truly handled by the coordinator to not create a scrollview+textview every time the text change :)

Answer (score -4):

You can have a multi-line `TextField` in SwiftUI (you just need to call `.lineLimit(N)` on it to become multi-line capable), but text with multiple separate styles isn't currently supported. A `TextField` just has a single font & style.

You can roll it yourself, though: create an `NSViewRepresentable` implementation that vends an `NSTextView` and bind it to an `NSMutableAttributedText` property. You'll need to handle all the text view model synchronization and bindings updates yourself, but it is certainly do-able.